# How to unsubscribe email from AWS SNS Topic?

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have an endpoint that subscribes the specified email to my SNS topic:

```
        [HttpPost("subscriptions/{email}")]
        public async Task SubscribeEmail(string email)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = new SubscribeRequest()
                {
                    TopicArn = AwsServicesConstants.SenderTopicArn,
                    ReturnSubscriptionArn = true,
                    Protocol = "email",
                    Endpoint = email,
                };

                var response = await _snsClient.SubscribeAsync(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Unexpected error: {ex}");
            }
        }
```

How can I unsubscribe given email from that topic with just a specified email like this

```
[HttpDelete("subscriptions/{email}")]
public async Task<UnsubscribeResponse> UnsubscribeEmail(string email)
{
    var request = new UnsubscribeRequest(email);

    var response = await _snsClient.UnsubscribeAsync(request);

    return response;
}
```

Actually, unsubscription is not working because `UnsubscribeRequest` requires only subscriptionArn, and **not** the email

Answer (score 2):

You can write app logic to get the ARN value using the email address. Here is a C# example that shows you the logic for this use case using the AWS SDK for .NET.

```
     public async Task<string> UnSubEmail(string email)
        {
            var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
            var arnValue = await GetSubArn(client, email);
            await RemoveSub(client, arnValue);
            return $"{email} was successfully deleted!";
        }

  public static async Task<string> GetSubArn(IAmazonSimpleNotificationService client, string email)
        {
            var request = new ListSubscriptionsByTopicRequest();
            request.TopicArn = TopicArn;
            var subArn = string.Empty;

            var response = await client.ListSubscriptionsByTopicAsync(request);
            List<Subscription> allSubs = response.Subscriptions;

            // Get the ARN Value for this subscription.
            foreach (Subscription sub in allSubs)
            {
                if (sub.Endpoint.Equals(email))
                {
                    subArn = sub.SubscriptionArn;
                    return subArn;
                }
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }


 public static async Task<string> RemoveSub(IAmazonSimpleNotificationService client, string subArn)
        {
            var request = new UnsubscribeRequest();
            request.SubscriptionArn = subArn;
            await client.UnsubscribeAsync(request);

            return string.Empty;
        }
```

You can find full .NET Example in the AWS Code Lib:

[Build a publish and subscription application that translates messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sns_example_cross_SnsPublishSubscription_section.html)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to identify the subscription (once subscribed) by calling [ListSubscriptionsByTopic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_ListSubscriptionsByTopic.html), looking for the Endpoint that matches the desired email address. You could then extract the ARN and use it when calling [Unsubscribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Unsubscribe.html).